# how can an attacker circumvent this

Tags: html, security

```
< select name = " user [ role ]" id = " user_role " >
< option disabled = " disabled " value =" admin " > admin </ option >
< option disabled = " disabled " value =" lecturer " > lecturer </ option >
< option value =" student " > student </ option >
</ select >
```

i was asked to find the vulnerability in the code snippet for a class

I tried to put this into an HTML viewer but the result is just the same code snippet. So i couldnt figure out how this would look on an actual website. I am guessing its just clicking a button, and the buttons for admin and lecturer are disabled?

we have only learned about injections and bufferoverflow in this class. Since this is only clicking on a button i dont understand how an attacker could circumvent this? since there is no input he needs to type in?

edit: they mentioned that this is on the client-side. I read somewhere that injection attacks should be prevented from the server-side.. could this be the case for this attack as well?

Comment: They probably want you to find a way to choose options "admin" or "lecturer" even though they are disabled.

Comment: but how could i do that without any other input from my side?

Comment: This is not on topic for Stackoverflow, it's more of a [security](https://security.stackexchange.com) question. But generally I'd rather read the source material or ask another student / assistant / professor / whatnot than there.

Comment: Where does the HTML originate from?

Comment: This is client-side code so the attacker can just remove the `disabled="disabled"` attributes. Or just send a query manually with any values.

Comment: How can they pick it, pretty simple remove the disabled attribute

Comment: but how do you remove the disabled attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the spaces in your tags, it should appear when you open it in a web browser.

```
<select name = " user [ role ]" id = " user_role ">
<option disabled = " disabled " value =" admin "> admin </option>
<option disabled = " disabled " value =" lecturer "> lecturer </option>
<option value =" student "> student </option >
</select>
```

I believe that is part of a form and an attacker could view the source and use the form method carry out an attack in which he acts as the admin or lecturer.
Check [this out](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/html-injection-tutorial/), it may help.

Comment: thank you so much! i had no idea that html injection  is a thing hehe

Comment: hehe yeah well maybe it used to be once.